# C Documentation for AVR Atmel Studio

Tags: avr, c, atmel-studio, documentation

I am new to AVR programming and have tried couple of tests on assembly language and were successful.

However, I would like to try out programming in C with Atmel Studio.

Could somebody tell me where I can find the complete documentation of what is available for C language in Atmel Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atmel Studio 6 provides the [Atmel Software Framework](http://www.atmel.com/tools/avrsoftwareframework.aspx) which is a massive, if bloated, set of libraries for all the various hardware configurations that Atmel offers. Atmel has done a pretty good job of using doxygen in these libraries so you can find a pretty thorough set of documentation [here](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/).

The ASF is fairly well integrated into the IDE with some C example projects which should work out of the box (assuming you are using a dev kit or otherwise supported hardware).

The [avr-Libc documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/) is also a great source of information about this particular flavor of C. The rest is mostly gcc C syntax.

Lastly, while EE.SE is a great site, for AVR specific things you also might want to try asking a question over at [AVR Freaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/). I think the ASF documentation is relatively self-explanatory, but for things like project setup and tool-chain problems, that site is probably your best bet.